# Add a constraint that would allow only one foreign key record per table in a 24 hour period?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a table that would only allow one member (FK) entry every 24 hours?

Its supposed to replicate the way in which some gyms only allow members to login once a day.

Is this possible to do in SQL Server? Or is there an alternative route for this?

Comment: please illustrate your question with some sample data. It will help us to understand your question better

Comment: That sounds like a check that should be carried out in the application, not the database.

Comment: You compare this to being able to use the system once a day, however, that isn't what you describe. For someone that can use something once a day, the values `2020-05-24T19:00:00` and `2020-05-25T09:00:00` would be valid, as they are on separate days. You, however, seem to suggest that would be invalid as they are less than 24 hours between the two. The former is easy with a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, the latter is not; you would have to go down a scalar function route. If it is the latter, I agree that this seems better handled in the application.